# How to read a specific row in excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I want to read single row from an Excel_file1, Sheet1, Row number 7 using python, any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) of [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) library:

You would need to install `pandas` and `xlrd` first:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
df = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Now, you can filter your dataframe to get any specific row using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

```
df.iloc[6] ## This will give you 7th row
```

Answer (score 10):

First install xlrd

```
pip install xlrd
```

then open python file and

```
import xlrd 

# Give the location of the file 
loc = ("path of file") 

# To open Workbook 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

print(sheet.row_values(7))
```

location is relative path not absolute path.

To read more about xlrd and its usage visit https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Happy coding.